# How to map from MainWindow to a QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I am attempting to spawn a custom QGraphicsItem inside my scene, but am unsure of how exactly to map the point from its origin to the Item. My location comes from a dropEvent in my MainWindow:

```
void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    QPointF dropPos = ui->GraphicsView->mapFrom(this, event->pos());
    vModule *module = new vModule(dropPos);
    ui->GraphicsView->scene->addItem(module);
}
```

This is my vModule.cpp:

```
vModule::vModule(QPointF dropPos)
{
    QPointF pos = mapFromScene(dropPos);
    setX(pos.x());
    setY(pos.y());
    // ...
}

// Event handler implementation, shouldn't be relevant
```

And my vModule.h:

```
class vModule : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    explicit vModule(QPointF dropPos);
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;

protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
}
```

This is the closest to what I logically thought the conversion would be, but it is quite wrong in practice, more wrong than simply passing the position from the event as-is (which is a constant difference in position from the main window?). Can anyone correct my error?

Comment: So, I sort of fixed the problem, by mapping the coordinate... three times. Starting with the drop coordinate, I map in the following way:
    
    drop location -> drawArea(mapFromParent) -> drawArea(mapToScene) -> graphicsItem(mapFromScene)

All of these mappings are done in the MainWindow. There has got to be a better way to do this though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of vModule, you're calling mapFromScene before the widget has even been added to the scene.

Add the Widget first then set its position. Also, if you think about it, you're going from global (screen) coordinates to local widget coordinates. This function may be of use, assuming the drop event coordinates are in screen space: -

> QPoint QWidget::mapFromGlobal(const QPoint & pos) const

which Qt help defines as: -

> Translates the global screen coordinate pos to widget coordinates.

Comment: DropEvents are created in global coordinates? I did not know this. Is this dependent on where the drag event was created? Additionally, mapping from global coordinates, keeping the mapping in vModule the same, didn't work. The drop location is way off if the window is resized, which leads me to believe the mapping in vModule is wrong.

Comment: The solution I posted as a comment to my question works, but there has to be a better way to do it...

Comment: If you're not using mapFromGlobal, break the problem down into smaller steps. Without using the drop coordinates, you'd just create an object, add it to the scene and then set its scene position. So, with the drop coordinates, you need to get the view (drop) coords, map them to scene coords and then set the widget's position with that. Also, in the Widget constructor, using setPos will be more efficient as setX() calls y() and setY() calls x(). You should not need to call mapFromScene in the widget constructor as setPos sets coords relative to the parent or scene coords, if no parent exists.